# Is there a finite-index finite-depth II$_1$ subfactor which is more than $7$-super-transitive?

Tags: subfactors, von-neumann-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, open-problems

Background: See Noah and Emily's posts on subfactors and planar algebras on the Secret Blogging Seminar.

There are plenty of examples of $3$-super-transitive (3-ST) subfactors; Haagerup, $S_4 < S_5$, and others. There's exactly one known example of a $5$-ST subfactor, the Haagerup-Asaeda subfactor, and one $7$-ST subfactor, the extended Haagerup subfactor.

Below index $4$ there are the $A_n$ and $D_n$ families, which are arbitrarily super-transitive. Ignore those; I'm just interested above index $4$.

Is there anything that's even more super-transitive?

Comment: (Aside: I'm not asking this in the expectation that anyone will have an immediate answer --- if you have one, you should answer here and then hurry off and submit to a journal!)

I'm mostly asking here to record a bet with Emily Peters: if such exists, I owe her a bottle of champagne. If you can prove that none exist, she owes me a bottle of champagne. I win by default on my 60th birthday. 

Comment: Are the group-subgroup subfactors known to be less than $7$-supertransitive? Else by exploring the maximal inclusions of groups $(H \subset G)$ (and so the [primitive permutation groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_permutation_group), with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Datalib/prim.html)), perhaps we can find such a subfactor more than $7$-supertransitive.

Comment: A subgroup subfactor can be at most 3-supertransitive. The 4-box space is at least 15 dimensional. This can be seen by looking at the partition planar algebra (MR2972458).

Comment: I see, thanks Dave. In analogy with the [Mathieu groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group#Multiply_transitive_groups), we could expected the finiteness of finite depth,  index $>4$ and (at least) $4$-supertransitive  subfactors.

Comment: The partition planar algebras are the $(S_{n-1} \subset S_n)$ subfactor planar algebras. Perhaps the $3$-$ST$ finite group-subgroups subfactors are (up to equiv. and dual) limited to the infinite families  $(S_{n-1} \subset S_{n})$  and $(A_{n-1} \subset A_{n})$ plus finitely many others possibilities, perhaps coming from the Mathieu groups. In general, perhaps the finite depth finite index irreducible $3$-$ST$ subfactors are limited to some *well-known* infinite families plus finitely many *sporadic* examples. Idem for $2$-$ST$ (much harder) and for maximal $1$-$ST$ (much much harder).

Comment: @DavePenneys: thanks to the paper you cite ([here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1158v2.pdf) p13-14) if I'm not mistaken, for $k=1,2$ or $3$, $(R^G \subset R^H)$ is $k$-supertransitive iff the action of $G$ on $X=G/H$ is $k$-transitive, and so iff $G/H_G$ is a $k$-transitive group (of course it's false for $k > 3$). So the $3$-$ST$ group-subgroup subfactors are given by the $3$-$T$ groups (classification?). Also, if $G/H_G$ is a $2$-$T$ group then $(R^G \subset R^H)$ is $2$-$ST$, so maximal, so is $(H \subset G)$ and then $G/H_G$ is a primitive group.

Comment: @DavePenneys: warning $(R^{S_3} \subset R^{S_2})$ is $4$-$ST$ (but of course, what you've written is true if $[G:H] \ge 4$).

Comment: See the write-up [Classification of triply transitive finite groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698327/classification-of-triply-transitive-finite-groups) and [List of 2-transitive permutation groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16954/what-are-the-subgroups-of-operatornamealt2p-containing-the-normalizer-of/17863#17863) of Jack Schmidt.